# Manipulating an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

Long story short, I have an array of JSON objects with no keys.I am trying to push each object through HTML, however, I have repeating data that I would like to merge. I am getting this array through an AJAX call, not sure if I should implement something during the call or after.

My Data looks like this:

```
myData =[{Title:'Test', Dates:'11/12/14-/n11/14/14', Code:'A1B2C3'},
         {Title:'Test', Dates:'10/12/14-/n10/14/14', Code:'D1E2F3'},
         {Title:'Test', Dates:'11/12/14-/n11/14/14', Code:'D1E2F3'},
         {Title:'Test2', Dates:'01/12/14-/n01/14/14', Code:'H1J2K3'}]
```

The AJAX looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ckURL,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        myData= data;
    }
});
```

I would love to have myData to look like:

```
myData =[Test:{Dates:['11/12/14-/n11/14/14','10/12/14-/n10/14/14'], Code:['A1B2C3','D1E2F3']},
         Test2:{Dates:'01/12/14-/n01/14/14', Code:'H1J2K3'}]
```

Or like this:

```
myData =[{Title:'Test', Dates:['11/12/14-/n11/14/14','10/12/14-/n10/14/14'], Code:['A1B2C3','D1E2F3']},
         {Title:'Test2', Dates:'01/12/14-/n01/14/14', Code:'H1J2K3'}]
```

If you have an idea of how to go about this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading up to this point.

Comment: Do some research into how to create a *"groupBy"* object that you can then iterate to generate the final mapped array

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome on board!

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are your friends.

Here is an example of how to get to the first structure you posted:

```
myData.reduce((data, item) => {
  const d = data[item.Title];
  if (d) {
    d.Dates.push(item.Dates);
    d.Code.push(item.Code);
  } else {
    data[item.Title] = {
      Dates: [item.Dates],
      Code: [item.Code]
    };
  }
  return data;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped a lot.

How would I go along doing the second structure? Will it follow the same Map and Reduce functions?

Comment: Yes would generate the second structure using `map()` and maybe `reduce()`. Just take a look at the documentation, give it a try and if you can't figure it out, let me know.